# import from foxpro return error file is not exist reasons

Tags: firefox

My code:

```
    fileName = GETFILE('XLS')
   IF LEN(ALLTRIM(fileName)) < 1 THEN 
   MESSAGEBOX("ôàéë íå âûáðàí",1)
   RETURN
   endif
fileLength = GETWORDCOUNT(fileName,"\")
fileNumber = GETWORDNUM(fileName, fileLength,"\")
lc_f = GETWORDNUM(fileNumber,1,".")
getFreePosition = ""
indexNumber = 1

DO WHILE indexNumber < fileLength 
    getFreePosition = ALLTRIM(getFreePosition)+ALLTRIM(GETWORDNUM(fileName,indexNumber,"\"))+"\"
    indexNumber = indexNumber + 1
ENDDO 
CREATE CURSOR xlsfile(AccountName CHAR(20), TrafficSourceCommunicationName CHAR(20), CommunicationScheduledFor CHAR(20), CommunicationStartDate CHAR(20), CommunicationTemplate CHAR(20), Fromv CHAR(12), Tov CHAR(12), MessageId CHAR(45), SendAt CHAR(35), CountryPrefix  CHAR(2), CountryName CHAR(16), NetworkName CHAR(21), PurchasePrice CHAR(2), Statusv CHAR(25), Reason CHAR(25), Action CHAR(25), ErrorGroup CHAR(25), ErrorName CHAR(80), DoneAt CHAR(15), Textv CHAR(254), MessagesCount CHAR(2), ServiceName CHAR(16), UserName CHAR(19), SeenAt CHAR(19), Clicks CHAR(19), PairedMessageId CHAR(19), DataPayload CHAR(19))

   IMPORT FROM getFreePosition+lc_f".xls" TYPE XL8
```

returns error: file is not exist
I can't understand. Function GETFILE() gives us options for choosing file and this block works correctly.
Where is the mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Alex, 
just add + between   lc_f   and   ".xls"  . 
It should work fine after that. 
Cheers, 
Sime 
PS In most situations APPEND would suite you better than IMPORT but either 
one does the job.